# Can someone help me identify this circuit symbol please?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, schematics

I'm trying to fix something and there is a component on the schematic that I don't recognize. Is this symbol supposed to represent a jumper?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a link in the copper - not an actual component.

Also known as a "net-tie" (thanks @Spehro Pefhany)

It looks like it is from Cadence/Allegro.

The main value is that it allows nets of different names to be connected. Each of those names may have different attributes (eg trace width).

I used one today to force a trace to go to a specific place on a ground plane to avoid voltage drop affecting a sensitive analog measurement. Without this the source would have directly connected to the ground plane which could have had an additional voltage drop.

As noted by @le_top in the comments the "Place Near" attribute can be very useful in these situations.

Comment: Also know as a "net tie"

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Ah thanks - I wondered what people called them.

Comment: I used this techique to enable specific power and ground routing and avoid copper poor or other undesired connections.  More specifically, an SDCARD resulted in a power surge in a low power circuit with serious side effects on the other components.  So I separated the power traces so that they came directly from the regulator and dedicated to the SDCARD, adding a BEAD and a capacitor close to the SDCARD.   This avoids that the current surge "steals" from "decoupling" capacitors for other components.  The comment "Place near L9530.2" suggests that the reason may be similar here.